# Group by with order by in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Blockquote

I have some confusion with the group by & order by combination. I have an Employee table with several columns. Like: `Name, Id, Sal, ServiceType,Center` etc.

I want to get all employees sorted by `ServiceType` and `Name` with in a given `Center`

Now this is what I have tried and of course it is not working.

```
SELECT servicetype, name, CentreCode 
FROM Employee 
GROUP BY CentreCode ORDER BY servicetype, name
```

Please help me with the correct query

```
table data
=========     
servicetype    name     CentreCode 
   1           lee         1
   1           john        1
   12          smith       2
   12          brown       3

output
======
servicetype    name     CentreCode 
   1           john        1
   1            lee        1
   12          brown       3
   12         smith        2
```

Comment: Don't tag products not involved... (Some dbms products are less standard compliant when it comes to GROUP BY...)

Comment: What to select if a `centerCode` has more than 1 record?

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY! (Not needed here...)

Comment: could you give us some example data from your table, your current result from that query and what you want to get as a result?

Comment: You are using 3 RDBMSs?

Comment: All the columns allow non-unique values. i.e. A column can have same value several times

Comment: No it's just sql-server. I edited tags

Comment: @Robert: Please show some sample data and the required output.

Comment: just as @jarlh said remove the group by just use `ORDER BY`. `SELECT servicetype, name, CentreCode 
FROM Employee ORDER BY CentreCode ,servicetype, name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT servicetype, name, CentreCode 
FROM Employee 
ORDER BY CentreCode,servicetype, name
```

Or for a specific Centre:

```
SELECT servicetype, name, CentreCode 
FROM Employee 
WHERE CentreCode='some code'
ORDER BY servicetype, name
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
SELECT servicetype, name, CentreCode 
FROM Employee 
GROUP BY servicetype, name, CentreCode 
ORDER BY servicetype, name
```

The fields using in Select clause must be the same in Goup by, other you can use an agregation function like that:

```
SELECT count(servicetype), count(name), CentreCode 
    FROM Employee 
    GROUP BY CentreCode 
    ORDER BY CentreCode
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions involved?

Comment: If you select "servicetype", "CentreCode" and Group By Only "CentreCode" - what would your output be if "servicetype" aren't the same ? (in MySQL you don't have to group by all columns, and you will get all the  rows). But if you  select "servicetype", "CentreCode" and group by 1, 2 it works even if "servicetype" aren't the same.(or group by one fields and using agregation function)